# Tight analysis on a custom data structures with Insert and Remove-Min

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I have a data structure supporting the operations `Insert(X)` and `Remove-Min()`. `Remove-Min()` is performed in $O(\sqrt{\log n})$. And I am supposed to show that the `Insert` is bounded by $\Omega(\log n)$.

I would like to ask how to approach this problem. $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ never really occured to me and I do not know how to start.

My attempt was: Since the best possible sorting is in $O(n \log n)$ one needs insertion in $\log n$ to be able to retrieve the current minimum element in $O(1)$. But then, this is not tight enough, plus the element should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to sort a list $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ using your data structure: insert all elements, and then repeatedly remove the minimum element.

You take it from here.

Comment: Hi @Yuval, can you please clarify, I still do not relate this to the square root.

Comment: The square root is a red herring. Any running time which is $o(\log n)$ would have the same effect.

Comment: Hmm, but why, I know that $O(\sqrt{\log n}) \nsubseteq O (\log(\sqrt n)) = O(\log n)$. So I do not fill confident that I can take $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ as $O(\log n)$ per se.

Comment: I’m sorry, but you’ll have to take it from here.